# Is $\sigma(\bigcup_{i \in I} \sigma(X_i))=\bigcup_{i \in I} \sigma(X_i)$?

Tags: measure-theory

In probability path, by Sidney Resnick, in page 83, the author defines the sigma-algebra generated by a family of r.v. indexed by an arbitrary set $I$, as $\bigcup_{i \in I} \sigma(X_i)$. However, I've seen it defined also as $\sigma(\bigcup_{i \in I} \sigma(X_i))$, and this one makes more sense, sinse when taking the union of sigma-algebras, we may not get a sigma-algebra.

So, is $\sigma(\bigcup_{i \in I} \sigma(X_i))=\bigcup_{i \in I} \sigma(X_i)$?

Or do we have a typo in Resnick's definition?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're right in that it should be $\sigma(\bigcup_{i \in I} \sigma(X_i))$.

But on the other hand, I think you have misread what Resnick actually wrote. I found a pdf of the book and looked at the page. What it actually says is:

> If for each $t$ in some index set $T$
>   $$ X_t : (\Omega,\mathcal{B}) \to (\Omega',\mathcal{B}') $$
>   then we denote by 
>   $$ \sigma(X_t, t \in T) = \bigvee_{t \in T} \sigma(X_t) $$
>   the smallest $\sigma$-algebra containing all $\sigma(X_t)$.

So it uses $\bigvee$ instead of $\bigcup$. Since you are actually reading the book (I only scrolled through the pdf to page 83) perhaps you can find the definition of the symbol $\bigvee$. (Or perhaps this statement on page 83 is defining *both* the notation $\sigma(X_t, t \in T)$ and *also* the notation $\bigvee$?)

Comment: You might be correct, however, in proof of proposition 3.2.6, page 82, the author writes $\{\bigvee_n X_n \leq x\}=\bigcap_n \{X_n \leq x \}$, so I'm interpreting as $\sup$, which when applied to sets gives $\bigcup$.

Comment: Oh, of course it's sup! How could I not come up with that. :-) Anyway, the sup of a bunch of $\sigma$-algebras, in the poset of $\sigma$-algebras, is apparently different from the sup in the (larger) poset of all sets (of subsets of $\Omega$).

Comment: By the way, in the a posterior proof, the author writes the correct expression as defining the expressing with \bigvee. ;)